# Why finding unique number among xn + 1 numbers by counting bits and then modulo by x works

Tags: algorithm, binary, unique

I know that if we have given array that looks e.g. like this: `[7,6,7,6,5,7,6]`, where every number is repeated `x` times except the one number that is unique in array, then we can:

1. Write numbers (it's binary representation) one above the other
2. Then we can count bits in the resuling columns
3. Then by doing (count from `i` column) mod x we will get binary representation of unique number contained in the array.

This process looks like:
[image]

It works. But why it works? I can't understand it. Please for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a certain bit (like the third-least significant bit) is 0 for the unique value, then we *know* that the sum of that bit's value over all input values must be a multiple of , since if it is set to 1 for one of the duplicate values, then we already have  of those. If it is also set for another of the duplicate values, then we have new set of ... each time getting a total that is a multiple of . So in that scenario, the sum of that bit modulo  is 0.

In the other case, where the unique number has a 1 for that particular bit, the sum will be one more than a multiple of  (same reasoning). And so the sum of that bit modulo  is 1.

This principle works in exactly the same way for every bit position.

Answer (score 1):

When you count bits, you'll get the same answer no matter what the order of the bits is. And therefore qe get the samw answer if you sort thr numbers.

But when you sort the numbers you get blockz of 'x' of the same number for the repeated one. Which means a block of 0s that adds to 0, or a block of 1s that is 0 mod 'x'. Either way, the repeated numbers disappear, leaving only the unique one.

Comment: I see. The count is `xy` (y is n except the numbers with `0` bit at `i` position), so it means that our unique number at this position has 0 bit. If the count is `xy + 1`, then at this position our number will have `1`.. Did I understand well?

Comment: @Szyszka947 Exactly.